# Как из полученного вложенного массива сделать новый вложенный массив?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть запрос который выводит вложенный массив

```
#items: array:6 [▼
       0 => App\Models\LearnQuestion {#1315 ▶}
       1 => App\Models\LearnQuestion {#1316 ▶}
       2 => App\Models\LearnQuestion {#1317 ▶}
       3 => App\Models\LearnQuestion {#1318 ▶}
       4 => App\Models\LearnQuestion {#1319 ▶}
       5 => App\Models\LearnQuestion {#1320 ▶}
]
```

внутри которого вот такие массивы

```
array: [▼
       "id" => "1"
       "name" => "Вопрос 1"
       "type_question" => "Одиночный выбор"
       "point" => "10"
       "test_id" => "1"
       "created_at" => "2022-09-02 10:13:01"
       "updated_at" => "2022-09-02 10:13:01"
       "answer" => "Ответ 1"
       "question_id" => "1"
       "correct" => "Нет"
]
array: [▼
       "id" => "2"
       "name" => "Вопрос 1"
       "type_question" => "Одиночный выбор"
       "point" => "10"
       "test_id" => "1"
       "created_at" => "2022-09-02 10:13:01"
       "updated_at" => "2022-09-02 10:13:01"
       "answer" => "Ответ 2"
       "question_id" => "1"
       "correct" => "Да"
]
```

Как мне вывести данные в таком виде

```
Array
(
       [0] =>Array
       (
              [0]=> 'Вопрос 1'
              [1]=> 'Ответ 1'
              [2]=> 'Ответ 2'
              [3]=> 'Ответ 3'
       ) 
       [1] =>Array
       (
              [0]=> 'Вопрос 2'
              [1]=> 'Ответ 1'
              [2]=> 'Ответ 2'
              [3]=> 'Ответ 3'
       ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по структуре все массивы помещаются в новый.

```
$new_array = [];
```

А даляя каждый массив добавляешь к существуещему.

```
$new_array[]= $array1;
$new_array[]= $array2;
$new_array[]= $array3;
```

Либо  [используй array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)